# I cannot log in to Gmail on iPad "this browser or app may not be secure"

Tags: ipad, safari, gmail

My usual Gmail accounts I can log into no problem.
But one rarely used account I put the Gmail address into and press next;
and I dont even get chance to put in password, goes straight to screen below.

Javascript is on, cookies allowed.
Using Safari, iPad2, iOS 9.3.5

I tried Dolphin browser but no luck.
Cannot install Chrome or Firefox - missed my chance.

There is going to be a media event on my worksite soon, so want this special Gmail which is the business name working (reserved it years ago).

[image]

Comment: If you need email, isn't there any mail app that you can use ? default one, mymail, Edison, etc. And if it's some video call related stuff, even the current browser doesn't work, let alone the one on iOS 9.

Comment: ..and i am trying app store to see which email app will work, thanks @ankii

Comment: I got it opened in Altamail app, just have to learn it a bit now.

Comment: Google makes its own Gmail app which I prefer over all iOS mail clients. It supports most of the features the web client uses, and is capable of handling multiple mail addresses in different domains. It is regularly updated as the web-client improves.

Comment: thank you @IconDaemon, I will give it a go, thanks for tidy up too.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually found another solution

Log onto Gmail on a desktop, change security settings to allow it to work with apps. Effectively, this seems to lower the security of the Gmail.